# How to filter table data with a menu list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a store directory that displays each store in a row that has table cells with various store information. To help filter the results, I also have a list of store types such as Men's Fashion, Women's Fashion etc in a basic

```
<li>--Store Type--</li>
```

format.

When a user clicks on one of these list items, say Men's Fashion, I'd like it to filter all of the table rows containing the term Men's Fashion, and hide the ones that do not have this term. Some table cells will have multiple terms as some stores sell both Men's and Women's fashion, so I'd like for it to filter based on all of the terms and not just a single term.

How would I go about doing this using jQuery?

Here is my list structure

```
<ul>
   <li>Women's Fashion</li>
   <li>Men's Fashion</li>
   <li>Shoes &amp; Footwear</li>
   <li>Communication &amp; Technology</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my table structure

```
<tr class="row" data="">
   <td class="name list-background-dark">Ted Baker<img class="store-logo" src="Logo.jpg" alt="Ted Baker" title="Ted Baker"></td>
   <td class="location list-background-dark"><span class="location-image-dark">Level 1</span></td>
   <td class="numeric number"><span class="telephone-dark">5555555</span></td>
   <td class="category"><span class="category-dark">Men's Fashion, Women's Fashion, Communication &amp; Technology</span></td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything with JS yet?

Comment: @ExplosionPills for this particular example no, as I'm still learning it's a bit out of my depth so I thought I'd ask for the best way to go about finding a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** my previous answer used [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/), but a better option is [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(".row").hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(".category span").text().indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
}).show();
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/WrgPA/1/).

#### Details:

This selects all rows, hide them, and returns the same array

```
$(".row").hide()
```

... which will then be passed to `filter` (which will filter it by some condition).

```
$(".row").hide().filter(function() {
    // "this" refers to the element being tested
    return ...
});
```

What we want are rows that have an element with the `category` class, and inside its `span` there should be the text we're looking for:

```
$(this).find(".category span").text().indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0
```

Last, the resulting elements are shown:

```
}).show();
```

Comment: I don't think there is a `.grep`, just `$.grep`, but I'm not positive

Comment: @ExplosionPills that right, and it seems it doesn't work the way I expected. I'm testing it on jsFiddle and will fix my answer soon. (*Update:* done!)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Would it be possible to also set up an alphabetical filter? Much the same way as the store type, but another list containing the letters ABCDEF etc to go along with the store type filter that filters the store name by the first letter.

Comment: @SteveStevenson First, I was stupid, `grep` is only good for regular arrays, for jQuery elements it's a lot simpler to use `filter`. See my updated answer. Second, you can use any condition you want, just define your search criteria beforehand and, on `filter` callback, use them in conjunction to the current row. Take a look at the existing [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), so you can get any element inside the row being evaluated. Inspect them using `text`, `prop`, `val` etc and return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not you want it in the result.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Wonderful, it's all working as expected. Thank you again for your help and explaining the process.